# Is there some new way for tracking emails, instead of 1x1px gif, since now emails with it are disarmed?

Tags: php, html-email

I implement the script that is sending 1x1px gif but every email i send gets disarm.
I read that now email clients know about this way of tracking and they disarm message with this.Does anybody use any other way?

Comment: E-Mail clients ignore such _web-bugs_ a long time ago.

Comment: just give a link to your site if the person who receives the email like it will surely click it ,so you can track it when it reaches your web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1x1px image is still the main method. Facebook uses an additional method, similar concept, but using an [audio file instead](http://pandodaily.com/2012/03/06/facebook-knows-when-you-open-their-emails-how-creepy-silent-sounds/).

Comment: I wonder how accurate the audio file method is. What I wonder is how many mail clients actually support such files. I'd like to have some stats of that, would be an interesting read!

Comment: @RLacorne I'm sure it's just as segmented as the image technique. There must be some overlap (resulting in a more complete sample) or additional info gained, otherwise it would be pointless.

Answer (score 6):

There are no "new ways". There are some tricks to bypass client-side protection but none of them will work in all clients.

That problem dates back to... I don't know. Every modern mail client protects humanity against trackers like you. We don't need your tracking. That's it.

Don't track emails. Send them to people who want to get them, don't spam and don't try to get their IP addresses.

Sorry, I could not resist.

Comment: That is ok:) I am not a spamer. But that is probably something that spamer would say:) I just needed the answer. Thank you for your response. Greetings

Comment: Tracking is very common and very legitimate in email marketing. It allows marketers to better tailor the content they are delivering their audience. It is no different to using google analytics on your web page. @just lerning